# How to impersonate a logged on user to read registry key/values under HKEY_CURRENT_USER?

Tags: c++, winapi, registry, impersonation

I'm trying to **impersonate an already logged on user from a windows service** (which is started with a local system account).
My main objective is to be able to read some specific registry key/values under HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

I'm already able to start a new process with the user "identity" but it seems I'm unable to practice impersonation from any thread inside my service.

Here is the code I'm using, all seems to be ok except when I try to open a key which only exist under HKEY_CURRENT_USER for the logged on user:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <wil/resource.h>
#include <Wtsapi32.h>

// The *wil* namespace comes from the microsoft wil package: https://github.com/microsoft/wil. 
// You can just replace unique_handle by HANDLE and unique_hkey by HKEY to make this sample work.

void Impersonate()
{
    DWORD sessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

    // Get the primary user token
    wil::unique_handle hUserToken;
    if (!WTSQueryUserToken(sessionId, &hUserToken))
        return;

    // Get the impersonation token
    wil::unique_handle hImpersonationToken;
    if (!DuplicateToken(
            hUserToken.get(), SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL::SecurityImpersonation, &hImpersonationToken))
        return;

    // Impersonate ?
    if (!SetThreadToken(NULL, hImpersonationToken.get()))
        return;

    // Also tried by using ImpersonateLoggedOnUser :
    // if (!ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hUserToken.get()))
    //    return;

    // Not working
    // (I just created a 'Fake' key under HKEY_CURRENT_USER for the logged on user)
    wil::unique_hkey hKey;
    LSTATUS status = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Fake", 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hKey);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != status)
    {
        // Get ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error
    }

    RevertToSelf();
}
```

Is it possible (by using impersonation) to read registry values under HKEY_CURRENT_USER ?
And if yes, what is wrong in this code ?

Comment: you not need impersonation. you need query user *SID* and open key by sid

Comment: Well, I just discovered you cannot use *HKEY_CURRENT_USER* within applications which impersonates. You have to first call [*RegOpenCurrentUser*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopencurrentuser) to get the "good" root key. I wonder now if there is a "fluent" way to use either *HKEY_CURRENT_USER* or RegOpenCurrentUser when you write some registry helpers functions...

Comment: `RegOpenCurrentUser` - open thread token and query it sid, then format key path based on this sid. instead impersonate, then again open token, better direct query it

Comment: "*RegOpenCurrentUser uses the thread's token to access the appropriate key, **or the default if the profile is not loaded**.*" You can alternatively load a user's profile via `LoadUserProfile()`, which takes a token as input (no impersonation needed), and one of the outputs is the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` handle for that user.

Comment: @EmmanuelHorrent Your presented code works for me on Windows 10 1909. It can access the "Fake" key under current user. Could your show your Windows version and detailed reproducible steps?